# How to access the elements of a dictionary variable in React js

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

In the following code fragment, I get the token information of the user who is logged in.

```
async getToken(accessToken){
        try {
            let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(accessToken);
            console.log("getToken: " + token);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("something went wrong gettoken")
        }
 },
```

This token information returns to me like this.

```
{"auth_token" : "2jk34k23jh42lklasdfqwpoerp12134saqwoswc"}
```

I just need to access the token information on the 2nd parameter. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can access it with

```
token["auth_token"]
```

Comment: @eddasahin61 Are you sure that it's not empty? Can you put a breakpoint there and check the contents of `token`?